# Hector mapping stabilized frame

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working in a robot and started to use the hector mapping package in replacement of gmapping.
I only have one doubt regarding the setting up your robot tutorial.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot

How can I provide the transformation between the base_link and base_stabilized, i have a mems imu and robot pose ekf implemented. So I simply add a new frame /base_stabilized) to tf???
Can anybody that already has this working in their robot help me out...
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31618/hector-mapping-stabilized-frame/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I also recently noticed that the description in the tutorial is a bit misleading, as the base_footprint described there is not rigidly attached to the robot as it is the case with most robot models out there. I'll have to think about how improve the description :)

Now for your specific problem: Yes, you have to get to transform from the IMU published to tf. If your robot actually experiences significant roll/pitch motion, that is. If it doesn't, the 'base_stabilized' frame is not needed, as described in the tutorial.

I uploaded a very simple helper node for publishing roll/pitch attitude data from imu to tf just a few minutes ago [here](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fhector_slam%2Fhector_imu_attitude_to_tf) (not yet indexed on ros.org).
So what should work is the following: Copy/Use the [example.launch](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/launch/example.launch) and use your imu topic there. For the base_frame you have to use a body-fixed frame of your robot, let's use 'base_footprint' as an example. You now only have to get your odometry publisher to publish 'base_stabilized → odom' instead of 'base_footprint → odom'.

For hector_mapping you can then set the following parameters:

```
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_stabilized" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
```

Let me know if that works for you.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2012-04-11**:
Thanks, yesterday I managed to solve the problem, i modified my urdf so that the root link is base link. Created a node similiar to yours that publishes the roll a pitch of the base_stabilized -> base_link,

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2012-04-11**:
A a static transform publisher that gives me the base_footprint to base_stabilized height in my case the radius of the robot wheels. I was going to publish the answer also, but you explained it better. Thanks you.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2015-06-13**:
Stefan,
I would certainly like to see the example launch that you created.  I am also struggling to learn Hector mapping.

Thank you very much,
Morpheus

**Comment by [casper911ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/21126/casper911ca/) on 2015-07-31**:
fmarques, how do you modify the urdf? I'm assuming there is an existing file somewhere. When I search for urdf, I get dozens of files; pr2.urdf.xacro, urdf.rvis, etc. many located in ros/indigo/share/